# Problemas con envio de mensaje desde la app de whatsapp

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp

Tengo un problema con mi código, este codigo corre bien mientras el numero este registrado en whatsapp pero si no es asi se queda tildado en la busqueda de contactos para enviar el mensaje. ¿Cómo podria solucionar este problema? De antemano agradezco la ayuda, dejo código :

Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShellExecute _
Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, _
ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Const SW_NORMAL = 1
Const mill As Double = 0.000000011574074

Sub mensaje_masivo()
Dim ran As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim mensaje As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

```
For Each ran In Hoja1.Range("TablaEnvio[mensase a enviar]")

    enviado = False ' Reinicia el valor de "enviado" en cada iteración
    
    mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & ran.Offset(0, 1).Value & "&text=" & "  ", " ", "%20")
    x = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", mensaje, vbNullString, vbNullString, SW_NORMAL)
    
    If x > 32 Then enviado = True ' Verifica si el mensaje se ha enviado correctamente
    
        Application.Wait (Now + mill * 1000)
        
        mensaje = VBA.Replace("whatsapp://send?phone=" & ran.Offset(0, 1).Value & "&text=" & ran.Offset(0, 0), " ", "%20")
        x = ShellExecute(hwnd, "Open", mensaje, vbNullString, vbNullString, SW_NORMAL)
   
        Application.Wait (Now + mill * 2000)
        Call SendKeys("{ENTER}")
        Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate
             
    
        
Next ran

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Mensajes enviados con exito.", vbInformation
```

End Sub